# WPF Control To Imitate HTML Console

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I'm guessing there's not a control that does this automatically, but I'm looking for a way to implement something like this in a wpf application. Here's what I'd like for it to do.

- Take commands into it like a cli (This could be a separate text box
  if necessary).
- Output normal text and support HTML colors.
- History that scrolls up as your cursor moves down after each command.
- HTML formatted divs, tables, and text formatting (no js needed)
- Small images no larger than 100x100

How do I start making this? Do I start with a StackPanel?

Comment: Not very clear what you need, but I'd start to consider to use a WebControl or, even better, CefSharp: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Answer (score 0):

```html
I Added two rows with four colomns in a grid panel
In the first row fourth colomn add a stackpanel for normal text

Out side the grid you also add image as well as inside 
That I include for your reference

The grid is nested in the scroll


<Window x:Class="Wpftest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpftest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="5" CanContentScroll="False"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="Augustus.jpg" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Augustus - 63BC - 14AD" />

            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="Tiberius.jpg" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="Tiberius - 42BC - 37AD"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4">

                <TextBlock FontSize="15">Your Normal text</TextBlock>

            </StackPanel>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Learn"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="10,5"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Learn"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="10,5"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Content="Inputs"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="10,5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```